# Setting the amount of exposure using RNcamera while taking pictures in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

i am using react-native-camera module to take pictures but i want to set the camera brightness via a slider, does this module support brightness settings like the one in samsung's native camera app

[image]

my current configurations are:

```
              <RNCamera
                    ref={ref => {
                        this.camera = ref;
                    }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use camera',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
                        console.log(barcodes);
                    }}
                />
```

Answer (score 1):

Use exposure={1}
Change number params.
Example:

```
            <RNCamera
                    exposure={2}
                    ref={ref => {
                        this.camera = ref;
                    }}
                    style={styles.preview}
                    type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                    flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                    androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use camera',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
                        title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
                        message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
                        buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                        buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                    }}
                    onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
                        console.log(barcodes);
                    }}
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for brightness yet , There is a pull request to handle that , you can check it :  [Added brightness adjustment support for Android #1779](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/pull/1779)